# What racquet is most similar to TT Warrior?

Tags: equipment, tennis, racket

Unfortunately the great [Prince Tripple Threat Warrior](http://www.tennis-warehouse.com/Reviews/TTW/TTWReview.html) tennis racquet was discontinued in 2009, with no clear replacement.

What tennis racquets available now on the market would be most similar in specs to this great classic, and would have a similar feel such that I could use it as a replacement?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at any of the Prince Original Graphite (POG) models as a replacement? I would have a look at the TT Warrior specs here and then go looking for a racquet with similar head size, weight, balance, and stiffness to get a similar replacement. http://www.tennis-warehouse.com/descpageRCPRINCE-TTW.html

Comment: Tennis Warehouse has a nice tool for finding "similar racquets" based on specs.  [Here is what it brings up for the TT Warrior.](http://www.racquetfinder.com/?pcode=TTW&hsMin=94&hsMax=100&lMin=26.9&lMax=27.1&wMin=11&wMax=11.6&swMin=319&swMax=331&fMin=65&fMax=69&current=N)  This could at least give you some ideas for some current racquets you could demo, since it's hard to gauge a precise feel for a racquet off specs alone.

Comment: @skc have you considered formulating an answer? you provide a way one can go about finding a similar racket and a way one can find out if the feel of the racket works for the user or not.

Comment: @jamauss see my comment to skc as it also applies to you.